# trying to call fortran subroutine in c++

Tags: c++, fortran

I have very limited knowledge of C++ and even less of fortran, I am currently trying to call a fortran subroutine from a c++ main. Following some examples I was able to come up with the following code to call the

```
subroutine fireballess(ear,ne,parames,ifl,photar,photer)
```

here is my C++ code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void fireballess_( double *fear, int fne,double* fparames, int fifl, double *fphotar, double *fphoter);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ne,ifl;
    double *ear;
    double *parames;

    double *photar;
    double *photer;


    parames = new double[9];

// parames=[4.3,0.23,0.5,0.5,1.5,1.,1000.,2.15,3.]
        parames[0]=4.3;
        parames[1]=0.23;
        parames[2]=0.5;
        parames[3]=0.5;
        parames[4]=1.5;
        parames[5]=1.;
        parames[6]=1000.;
        parames[7]=2.15;
        parames[8]=3.;

ne = 2;

    ear = new double[ne];
 ear[0] = 0.;
 ear[1] = 20.;
 ear[2] = 40.;
 ifl=2;

    photar = new double[ne];
    photer = new double[ne];

    // Call a Fortran subroutine
    //subroutine_sum_(&size,vec,&sum);
    fireballess_(&ear,ne,&parames,ifl,&photar,&photer);

    cout << "Calling a Fortran subroutine" << endl;
    cout << "===============================" << endl;

for (int i=0;i<=ne;i++){
    cout << "ear = " <<ear[i-1]<< " - "<<ear[i] << endl;
    cout << "photar = " << photar[i] << endl;
    cout << "photer = " << photer[i] << endl << endl;
}

    delete[] ear;
    delete[] parames;
    delete[] photar;
    delete[] photer;
}
```

however, when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
call_fortran.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
call_fortran.cpp:45:53: error: cannot convert ‘double**’ to ‘double*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void fireballess_(double*, int, double*, int, double*, double)’
     fireballess_(&ear,ne,&parames,ifl,&photar,photer);
```

which I do not understand, since the photer variable follows the very same path of the photar variable, that gives no errors instead.
I hope someone with a better understanding of pointers than me can help me here.
Thanks

Comment: If you want us to comment on whether the prototype corresponding to the Fortran subroutine is correct, please show declarations of that subroutine's arguments.

Comment: `ear` is already of type `double *`, so `&ear` is of type `double **`, which differs from your decleration `double *fear`

Comment: @francescalus I suppose this is what you are referring to:
`integer ne,ifl`
`real*4 ear(0:ne),parames(10),photar(ne),photer(ne)`

Comment: @BennyK thanks, eliminating the & worked with the compilation. Now I am getting a segmentation fault instead -.-"

Comment: I also want to add that "ne", "ifl", "ear", "parames" and so on are dangerously close to identifiers contained in namespace std, which is why `using namespace std;` [**should generally be avoided**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), because else things in std could shadow identifiers in your code or the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ear` is of type `double*` so that `&ear` is of type `double**`, which is not ok for the fortran function prototype. Getting rid of the `&`s *might* solve the issue (&parames, &photar and &photer are also double**):

Change

```cpp
fireballess_(&ear,ne,&parames,ifl,&photar,&photer);
```

to

```cpp
fireballess_(ear,ne,parames,ifl,photar,photer);
```

The fortran function prototype seems to be `void fireballess_(double*, int, double*, int, double*, double)`. If that is really so, then `photer` still has to be changed to `photer[i]` where (i is an array-index like 0, 1, 2...).

If you really want to understand what is going on, I suggest reading a good C++ Pointer Tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, as you and  BennyK pointed out that was the problem. I couldn't understand it since the error seemed to point to only one of the variables involved. The code compiles correctly now, even if I get a segmentation fault at runtime -.-"

Comment: 1. Run it with a debugger
2. see which line throws the segfault 3. find out which access in that line exactly throws the segfault 4. find out how it came to the invalid access. **OR even better:** *Don't use raw pointers at all.* (In your case, you could use std::vector<double> or std::array<double, n> instead).

Comment: the call to the subroutine is causing the segmentation fault apparently, I found it out trying to move it inside the for cycle: changing the code from: `fireballess_(ear,ne,parames,ifl,photar,photer);`
to `cout << "Calling a Fortran subroutine" << endl;
for (int i=0;i<=ne;i++){
    fireballess_(&ear[i],ne,parames,ifl,&photar[i],&photer[i]);
    cout << "ear = " <<ear[i-1]<< " - "<<ear[i] << endl;
cout << "photar = " << photar[i] << endl;
}`
returned a working code up to the fireballess call. I'll go back to testing later, thanks